# Does not having the full (good) payment history on report negatively affect me?

Tags: credit-score, credit, credit-report, credit-history, fico-score

I've had my credit card since 2006.  My credit-report reports the following:

```
Status: Open/Never late.
Date Opened: 06/2006
Reported Since: 06/2011
Date of Status: 09/2014
Last Reported: 09/2014
```

In addition to that it gives me a month by month payment history since `06/2011`.  So it is missing the detailed information of 5 years of good payments.

Does this missing history negatively affect me?  I realize that it also says `Open/Never late` and its been opened since `2006`, but will some lenders only see this as a 3 year old account?  Will it negatively affect my credit score?

American Express says they are unable to resend my payment history (but i can download it online) and Experian says that they would need American Express to resend it in order to add the payment history.  If it is affecting me negatively, what can I do about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The date opened (6/06) is there, and any negative remarks would be there for 7 years, and there are none. This minor detail, lack of specific history, isn't anything to be concerned with.